# How to add prefix/suffix commands to my spigot plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I have recently started work on a plugin with a good few commands, but was unaware of how to add prefix/suffix commands (e.g. `/prefix <prefix>`, `/suffix <suffix>`).

*EXAMPLE:* Someone named ExampleName types `/prefix &4[SomeCooLPrefix]`<sup>*</sup>. When they talk in chat, it should say `[SomeCoolPrefix] ExampleName: <message>`, where SomeCoolPrefix is in `ChatColor.RED`

**&4 is the code for ChatColor.RED*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider posting Spigot related questions to the [Spigot Forums](https://www.spigotmc.org/forums/spigot-plugin-development.52/), as it is more likely that people there will know the ins and outs of the Spigot API.

As for your question, although I haven't done anything with Spigot in a while, you'll have to use the

> ASyncPlayerChatEvent

Event in order to process when a player is chatting and then format the chat using the event.format(); method.

Also, if you're looking to allow players to give themselves a prefix AND save it, consider using a config file. I strongly recommend looking at the Spigot API documentation before trying to make a plugin.

Check out [this link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent&method=setFormat), and [the documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/player/AsyncPlayerChatEvent.html) for more regarding the ASyncPlayerChatEvent method.